# Can I secure a 12v battery to my bicycle to charge it? And then attach a 12v horn to it?

Tags: batteries

I'm from the Netherlands, so first let's clear this misconception up; I mean an *actual* bike, as in: [image]
<sub>(source: [fietsenverhuurschiermonnikoog.com](http://www.fietsenverhuurschiermonnikoog.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/giant-single-4u-heren.jpg))</sub>
.

Then I want to attach a 12 volt horn to it. I could just put it in the basket. It doesn't *necessarily* need to be charged while pedaling, or it can just be partly charged, but just that it runs out of power a bit slower. Then I'd like to attach a horn to it. And then have some fun.

Would this be possible? Thanks for reading my question. If I'm doing something wrong on here, please tell me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I'm Dutch too. I assume you know this is illegal?)

A 12V accu needs around 15V while charging. You could get some juice at that level out of a standard 6V dynamo by using a voltage-doubling rectifier:

[image]

(do not use the 'earth' connection, just the + and -. 1N400x will do for the diodes, 1000uF 35V (to be on the safe side) for the elco's.

I asssume you won't be carrying a standard 12V car accu with you? A standard headlamp is 6V 0.5A, so after doubling you might hope for let's say 100..200mA. A 50Ah car battery would take 250 .. 1000 hours of cycling to get charged. (depending on a lot of unknow factors)

You should not overcharge a car accu, but I think that is the least of your worries :)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Well I don't know exactly what would be the best, but for this project, I could try putting a car accu in my bike basket :) I don't know exactly how much it weighs but I'll be able to handle it I think.